# getting session information works only once what is going on

Tags: session

try to get session data  from a joomla site with this code it work once but after logong out and in again get no more data.

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../..' )); 
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
$session = JFactory::getSession();
print_r($SESSION);
$user = JFactory::getUser();
echo $user;
$username=$user->get('username'); // username text same as database table
$userId = $user->get( 'id' );  //id text same as database table 
$useremail=$user->get('email'); // email text same as database table
echo "UserID is: ".$userId;
echo '</br>';
echo "UserName is :".$username; 
echo '</br>'; 
echo "User Email is :".$useremail;
```

the output is

```
JUserUserID is: 0
UserName is :
User Email is :
```

it worked for 1 session after that nothing

Comment: Where is this code located in your file system?  Application execution order could be the issue here, but without knowing the context of the code posted its impossible to properly troubleshoot.

Comment: It is an folder witch is in a folder in the rootf(public) of the webserver